# Joining multiple sql queries together into one row

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table called `Platforms` with the following columns:

- id, name, img, template_id

And another table called `Templates` with the following columns:

- id, tpl_name, body

How can I select all platforms so all the rows have id, name, img, template_id, tpl_name.

`template_id` in `Platforms` = `id` in `Templates`.

Can I do it with one query? If yes, what is the method called?

Comment: Look at [join](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/join.html).

Comment: And look too "WHERE clause between 2 tables".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a simple WHERE into a SELECT query :

```
SELECT p.id, p.name, p.img, p.template_id, t.tpl_name
FROM Platforms as p, Templates as t
WHERE p.template_id = t.id;
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can do it with one query and the method is called "a join between table Platforms and Templates":

```
SELECT * FROM Platforms 
               INNER JOIN Templates on Platforms.template_id = Templates.id
```

Answer (score 2):

> select    p.id, name, img, t.id, tpl_name, body from     platforms p
>   inner join templates t on t.id = p.template_Id

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Platforms.*
FROM Platforms
INNER JOIN Templates ON Platforms.template_id = Templates.id
```

That should do it, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 1):

You mean a simple `JOIN`?

```
SELECT id, name, img, template_id, tpl_name FROM platforms p 
JOIN templates t ON p.template_id=t.id
```

Alternativlely you could choose a cartesian product and reducing the result with a `WHERE`-clause:

```
SELECT id, name, img, template_id, tpl_name FROM platforms, templates 
WHERE template_id=id
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is one alternative too:

```
SELECT Platforms.id As PlatformId , name, img, 
Templates.id as TemplateId, tpl_name
FROM Platforms
INNER JOIN Templates  ON Platforms.template_id = Template.id
```